# Karate: How to get first N elements from a list?

Tags: arrays, list, karate

the response is a list of strings, like below:

```
[abc, def, ghi ...]
```

I want to get only the first 10 elements/indexes from this list/array.

can we use something like below?

```
 * def result = response[0-9]
```

is there any other way of doing it, I know the above code will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the JS [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
* def nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
* def some = nums.slice(0, 3)
* match some == [1, 2, 3]
```